# Can engines with a fixed nozzle in the angle of attack have the same effect as the thrust vectoring?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls, flight-dynamics, propulsion, missiles

[image]

If the figure above represents a missile at the angle of attack and we vector resolution the thrust output from the nozzle, we can see that the thrust is divided into sine and cosine parts. Does the cosine and sine section of thrust cause torque in the rocket about cg? does the cosine part produce nose down pitching moment ?

Edit: In the figure above, sine and cosine are named oppositely

Comment: "does the cosine part produce nose down pitching moment ?" -- why wouldn't that be exactly cancelled out by an opposite pitching moment from the "sine part"?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is no, the vector sum of the two components is along the axis T of the rocket.

Comment: [This NASA page](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/rocket/rktstab.html) should be helpful

Comment: @quiet flyer because the distance between sine part to cg is larger than cosine part .

Comment: @sophit in nasa page sine component of drag produce restoring moment about cg

Comment: That NASA page is confusing.  They ought to clearly state that the aerodynamic stability dynamics are not changed in any way depending on whether the engine is producing thrust or not.  Why introduce the three different cases if they are actually all identical in terms of the aerodynamic torque produced by a non-zero angle-of-attack?  If they are trying to highlight that it makes no difference whether the rocket is producing thrust or not, they ought to clearly bring that out, such as by keeping the AoA same in all three cases and only varying the thrust.  I give the page a failing grade!

Comment: @alizera look at this way-- any stabilizing or destabilizing contribution of the motor thrust will be the same regardless of whether the rocket is in the atmosphere or not.  If a rocket tended to stay "on course" just because the motor was thrusting, the dynamics of space flight would be a lot simpler-- no special guidance systems would be needed for any portion of the flight where the motor was firing, regardless of whether the rocket were in the atmosphere or not--

Comment: @alizera re "in nasa page sine component of drag produce restoring moment about cg" -- not the *sine* component of drag-- the *whole* drag vector.  Because it acts parallel to the flight path, and therefore *not* in line with the CG.  What does that have to do with the thrust vector and whether it does or does not produce a torque?

Comment: (Plus there's the whole other issue of whether we should choose to show the Drag vector as acting at the CP, or as acting as the CG *but also accompanied by an aerodynamic pitching torque or moment*.  Both are valid, but different.  We come to the same conclusions in the end either way.)

Answer (score 2):

The pitching moment from thrust vectoring comes from the trust axis' position relative to the center of gravity of the rocket or aircraft's body.  If the rocket motor, or jet engine, is rigidly attached to the body, and the extended line of the thrust axis passes through the body's C of G, there are no rotational moments.

It doesn't matter if the rocket motor is at the front, the back, or on a boom 50 feet ahead or behind. What matters is whether the thrust line passes through the C of G.

Thrust vectoring, by gimbal mounting the rocket motor, or using a vectoring nozzle on a jet engine, moves the thrust line to impart rotational moments about the C of G.
[image]

Comment: so in aircrafts why front prpoller engine mounted cause distablizing moment avout cg at angle of attack ?

Comment: @alireza -- are you sure it does?  Are you talking about something like P-factor-- in that case the thrust line does *not* pass through the center of the prop hub and therefore is *not* in line with the CG of the aircraft.  But there's no *direct* equivalent of P-factor as long as far as *pitch* dynamics are concerned.  Maybe you need to ask a new question about that, if you can sort your thoughts out well enough to ask a clear question --  of course there are effects related to propwash over the horizontal tail, but I don't think that's what you are asking about--

Comment: @alireza you have all kinds secondary effects once you add wings, tail, spinning propeller, etc. As far as the thrust force itself goes, that's how it works.  Ppl think jets with tail mounted engines are destabilized by the location of the engines at the back. If the engines are rigidly attached, it makes no difference where they are.

Comment: @quiet flyer Yes, the professor of the dynamics and control(flight mechanics) course of the University of India said that if a propeller engine is installed in front of the plane, it will cause longitudinal instability and cause the neutral point to move forward and decreace static margin

Comment: @quiet flyer I am not talking about the p-factor. What was explicitly said was that if a propeller engine is installed in front of the plane and the plane is at the angle of attack, the propeller will produce a vertical force, which is the cosine part of the thrust, and because this vertical force is ahead of the cg , it will cause 
longitudinal instability.

Comment: @alireza If it's moving the NP, that's the surface area of the propeller and spinner in profile having an effect, as if the prop was stopped horizontally, adding its footprint to the airplane's horizontal footprint. If the thrust line passes through the vertical center of mass, thrust does not impart a pitching moment; it's the same whether the prop is on the nose or tail. What does impart a pitch change is increased flow over the tail when power is changed, reducing trim speed for power increases, and increasing it with power reductions.

Comment: @alireza -- Re "What was explicitly said was that if a propeller engine is installed in front of the plane and the plane is at the angle of attack, the propeller will produce a vertical force, which is the cosine part of the thrust, and because this vertical force is ahead of the cg , it will cause longitudinal instability." -- then he is simply teaching things that don't make sense.  The logic here is not correct.  If there is such an effect, it is happening for some *other* reason.